# Shell scripting: Receiving error `cat: illegal option -- A` when passing `CA` as parameter to shell function, other 2 letter params work as expected

Tags: shell-script, cat

I thought this was a weird one-off glitch at first, but now I've found a second completely different bash function with the same behavior, so I'm reaching out for help because it's driving me mad.

**Context:** I'm working on a Mac with ZSH as my shell. I have a few helper scripts in the form of shell functions to automate a few things I do regularly. Most of them require a parameter to be passed. That parameter is a 2 letter country code (AU, CA, UK, DE, etc). Most of them work just fine, but there are two functions that fail when `CA` is passed as the parameter.

**The error:**

```bash
cat: illegal option -- A
usage: cat [-belnstuv] [file ...]
```

**Notes while testing, applies to both functions:**

- Confirmed directories exists.
- All other country codes work (US, UK, AU, DE, JP).
- Lowercase `ca` works.
- Other random 2 letter strings ending with `A` work.
- Other random 2 letter strings starting with `C` work.
- Using just `A` also works, as in `taillog A`.

**Failing function 1, ran with: `taillog CA`**

```bash
function taillog() {
    local grey="1;30"
    local red="1;31"
    local green="1;32"
    local yellow="1;33"
    local cyan="1;36"
    tail -f /Users/myUser/Sites/Country-"$1"/logs/error.log \
    | GREP_COLOR="$green" grep -E --color=always --line-buffered "(\[php7?:info\])|$" \
    | GREP_COLOR="$cyan" grep -E --color=always --line-buffered "(\[php7?:notice\])|$" \
    | GREP_COLOR="$yellow" grep -E --color=always --line-buffered "(\[php7?:warn\])|(?i:warn(ing))|$" \
    | GREP_COLOR="$red" grep -E --color=always --line-buffered "(\[php7?:error\])|(?i:error(s))|(?i:fatal)|$" \
    | GREP_COLOR="$grey" grep -E --color=always --line-buffered "(?i:debug)|$"
}
```

**Failing function 2, ran with `findChanged CA 600`**

```bash
function findChanged() {
    find /Users/myUser/Sites/Country-"$1"/public/wp-content/plugins -type f -cmin -"$2" -not -path "*/\.git/*" | more
}
```

All other country codes work as expected. What is it about `CA` that causes `cat` to complain? It's driving me batty.

Comment: You're saying you're on a Mac, you're using the linux tag, you're talking of bash functions and then saying you're using zsh, you're talking about scripts, but showing functions. Your error is from `cat`, but you're not showing any code using `cat`. Are you just trying to confuse us?

Comment: FWIW, some implementations of `cat` do support a `-A` option, which would be the equivalent of `cat -vte` supported by your `cat` implementation according to its usage message.

Comment: `grep -E --color=always --line-buffered` is GNU `grep` syntax, not macos grep syntax. `(?i:...)` is perl regex syntax, not `E`xtended regex syntax.

Comment: Try `(set -o xtrace; taillog CA)` to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, @StéphaneChazelas, for taking the time to help. As to your first comment, many humble apologies for using the term "bash" inappropriately and all the other things I wrote that offended you.

Comment: I wasn't trying to confuse anybody. I was equally confused. It's why I posted. Turns out that one of my ZSH plugins, "common-aliases" was injecting a global alias, `alias -g CA="2>&1 | cat -A"`, causing any input of `CA` to expand to `cat -A`. That's what was causing my troubles. Removing that line allows the shell *functions* listed above to execute as expected.

Comment: To your 3rd comment, I'm down for a better way to do that if you have one. The goal of that function is just to colorize certain keywords when I `tail` my error logs. I'm (obviously) not a shell wizard, although I do enjoy playing around with it immensely.

Thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that one of my ZSH plugins, "common-aliases" was injecting a global alias, `alias -g CA="2>&1 | cat -A"`, causing any input of `CA` to expand to `cat -A`. That's what was causing my troubles. Removing that line allows the shell functions listed above to execute as expected.